# SQS with Celery configuration

Tags: python, django, celery

I was trying to setup Amazon SQS for Celery and I have the below configuration:

```
BROKER_BACKEND = "SQS"
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'us-east-1',
}
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = # access id
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = # secret access key
os.environ.setdefault("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
os.environ.setdefault("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

BROKER_URL = 'sqs://'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300

CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = #queue name
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE
CELERY_QUEUES = {
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE: {
        'exchange': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
        'binding_key': CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE,
    }
}
```

In my SQS configuration on the AWS account, I have a queue with the name written in `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE`. When I run this locally, everything works...but for some reason it creates another queue on SQS with the name format `<user_id>-celery-pidbox`. Something like this: `MyUser-MacBook-Pro-local-celery-pidbox`.

Is this normal? Why would it be creating another queue when I have a queue created with the name specified? Otherwise, its working, not sure if that other queue is required or I missed something? Any help is appreciated, I could not find this in the docs.

**EDIT**

Turns out this is normal. For some reason django-celery does this, it creates a queue for each box that you have accessing the queue you want to access. They will fix this in a future release. If somebody knows how to fix this temporarily, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: do you have any updates on how solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a good behavior so you can monitor which instances (IPs or local names) are accessing your SQS account. It is just one request, so it won't cost you anything.

Comment: Are you sure about one request? Looks like it is polling it constantly (=wasting money).

Comment: A disadvantage is that it needs full SQS access.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set these:

```
 CELERY_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = False 
 CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
```

To disable that.

Comment: It's not working for me: I've added `CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES = False
CELERY_WORKER_ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = False` but still see celery workers are creating `celeryev- * ` and `` *-celery-pidbox` queues created  randomly. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect the Celery with SQS so you should create an celery app using the below code

```
from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker="sqs://",
        broker_transport_options={
            "queue_name_prefix": "{SERVICE_ENV}-{SERVICE_NAME}-"
        },
    )
    task_base = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(task_base):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return task_base.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask

    return celery
```

Using this code you will be able to connect the Celery with SQS.